# Css Transform Y in each pixel by pixel

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

My website has a header which is fixed to top.My website header top portion contains logo.Logo is pretty big about 140px in height.I want to transform header to the `Y` axis and hide header-top portion and show only The header-bottom portion which contains Navigation menu.As the header is fixed i have to apply a `padding-bottom` to move the main content below the header.But when I scroll the header top portion goes quickly to top and hides But due to the `padding-bottom` the main content does not goes as fast as `header-top` . So i want a way with `jquery/js` to transform the header top in a way so it transforms out pixel by pixel when i scroll down and stops when the headers height reaches.And vice versa about the scrolling towards top

`Hints : what about for loop?`

### My markups are

```
<header>
   <div class="header-top">
       <a class="logo" href="image/logo.png>
   </div>
   <div class="nav-menu">
       ............
   </div>
</header>
```

### What i have tried

```
headerTopHeight =  $('.header-top').innerHeight();


$(window).on('scroll', function(){
    if($(window).scrollTop() > menuChangeOn){     //here menuChangeOn is the position where menu will shrink 
        menu.addClass('menu-shrinked');           // here menu is header and menu shrinked decreases the header-bottom line  height


        if(menu.hasClass('menu-shrinked')){
             menu.css({
                'transform': 'translateY(-' + headerTopHeight + 'px)',
                '-webkit-transform': 'translateY(-' + headerTopHeight + 'px)',
                '-moz-transform': 'translateY(-' + headerTopHeight + 'px)',
                '-o-transform': 'translateY(-' + headerTopHeight + 'px)',
                '-ms-transform': 'translateY(-' + headerTopHeight + 'px)'
            });
        }


    } else{
         menu.removeClass('menu-shrinked');

         if(menu.attr('style') && menu.attr('style').length > 0){
             menu.removeAttr('style');
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: could you add `menu-shrinked` css definitions

Comment: `menu-shrinked` actually decreases the header-bottom line height

Answer (score 0):

If you want your header and the page content scroll in sync, you can do it by changing css property `top` of the header with the amount of scroll limited by the height of the `nav-menu`. You can also use `transform`, but this is cleaner.

```js
headerTopHeight =  $('.header-top').innerHeight();


$(window).on('scroll', function(){
  $("header").css({top: -Math.min($(window).scrollTop(),headerTopHeight)});
  var menu = $(".nav-menu");
  if($(window).scrollTop() > headerTopHeight)
    menu.addClass('menu-shrinked'); 
  else
    menu.removeClass('menu-shrinked'); 
});
```

```css
body {padding: 0px;}
header {height:100px; position: fixed; top: 0px; background: #EEE; width: 100%;}
#main-container {padding-top: 100px;}
.header-top {height:80px; background: #DDD;}
.nav-menu {height:20px; border-bottom: 5px solid #F00;}
.nav-menu.menu-shrinked {border-bottom-width: 2px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <header>
       <div class="header-top">
           This is logo
       </div>
       <div class="nav-menu">
           This is nav
       </div>
    </header>
      <div id="main-container">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque sodales volutpat vehicula. Suspendisse pharetra quis arcu nec tincidunt. Etiam ac ultrices ligula. Phasellus sem dolor, laoreet id massa nec, efficitur tristique augue. Praesent gravida viverra augue quis rhoncus. Nullam eget velit nec ex hendrerit accumsan. Duis rhoncus elit eu fringilla porttitor. Maecenas sollicitudin blandit ante, ac tempus tortor aliquet dignissim. Ut nec convallis ipsum. Proin fermentum, velit vel mollis placerat, est orci faucibus leo, in porttitor tortor diam et tellus. Suspendisse ultrices mattis dui at efficitur. Duis tincidunt ac lorem vitae fringilla. Duis placerat elit ut magna pulvinar efficitur.

    Quisque quis nunc eu sem tempor tincidunt id ac nibh. Aenean nibh dui, vehicula eget egestas eu, sagittis eu quam. Suspendisse congue tortor sit amet tortor venenatis, at elementum elit vestibulum. Morbi at nibh finibus, iaculis lacus sed, hendrerit tellus. Fusce quam massa, pharetra tincidunt elit ac, luctus rhoncus justo. Quisque nec justo et tellus blandit malesuada. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Vestibulum faucibus mattis tortor et rhoncus. Praesent quis augue gravida, condimentum lorem sit amet, imperdiet justo. In dictum dictum massa, at posuere nulla sagittis ac.

    In placerat pellentesque lectus, ut volutpat nulla accumsan non. Nunc vestibulum leo felis, in dapibus mi fermentum eu. Proin vel imperdiet orci. Morbi facilisis elit nisl, a porta tellus mollis vitae. Nulla finibus dapibus ornare. Donec interdum, risus id consequat ultrices, enim est ultricies quam, quis rhoncus metus metus non arcu. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Sed faucibus justo dolor. Vestibulum nibh nunc, congue at tortor non, vehicula finibus sem. Aenean sit amet sapien sem. Aenean condimentum tincidunt quam vitae malesuada. Maecenas quis faucibus tellus. Nulla at tempus augue, ac interdum leo. Phasellus id augue id turpis pulvinar posuere.

    Curabitur diam ipsum, gravida in est vel, commodo sagittis tellus. Donec sed quam eleifend, porttitor ligula nec, gravida magna. Pellentesque quis purus finibus, pellentesque dui vitae, vulputate nunc. Praesent ullamcorper, arcu eget eleifend ultricies, ante lacus consequat leo, vel volutpat ligula mi eget urna. Nullam viverra dictum erat quis tincidunt. Praesent varius maximus viverra. Suspendisse ac posuere magna. Maecenas varius, tortor ac pretium mollis, lorem ante pretium justo, non maximus lacus leo vel elit. Morbi lectus urna, auctor id vestibulum vel, venenatis quis odio. Phasellus facilisis fermentum dictum. Pellentesque id purus finibus, sollicitudin magna id, accumsan mauris. Sed id massa a leo pellentesque feugiat. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Duis at varius enim. Sed velit nibh, porta nec sollicitudin nec, iaculis ac nunc.

    </div>
```